# Get a list of SQL databases on a different domain

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get a list of SQL servers and the databases on those servers.  The problem is how to get that list for servers that are on a different domain.

For example, my current domain is: `thisdomain.location.net`

The servers I am trying to get information on are in: `otherdomain.otherlocal.net`

I do have a list of servers (example: `server1.otherdomain.otherlocal.net`) but I am wondering how to put the list of servers into a cursor or some other way to compile the list.

I can connect to the servers on the other domain, but I am trying to automate the process.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create linked Server for otherdomain

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx#SSMSProcedure

Then you can run your query like

```
SELECT otherserer.databasename.dbo.tablename


SELECT otherserer.sys.databases or

SELECT otherserer.master.dbo.sysdatabases
```

should return database name